# como puedo solucionar el error al dar valor con la variable int?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, consola, packages

[image: este error me aparece al darle un valor en la operación como puedo solucionarlo?]
me seria de mucha ayuda de verdad porque soy nuevo en esto de los lenguajes de la programación

Comment: Tan sencillo como leer y entender el mensaje: "la variable `resultado` no se usa nunca". Para solucionarlo es muy sencillo: ¡úsala!. Un `System.out.print(resultado);` es suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que bastaría con cerrar la función `main` es decir luego de la linea     `resultado = num1+num2;` agregar `}` .De igual forma los warnings se deben a que la variable `resultado` no esta siendo usada.

```
public class PrimerPrograma {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num1,num2, resultado;
      num1 = 10;
      num2 = 6;
      resultado = num1+num2;
      System.out.print(resultado);
    }
}
```